# Python int too large to convert to C long in python 3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, word2vec

I am getting this error when I am trying to run word2vec from gensim library of python. I am using python 3.4 and OS is windows 7. I have also attached complete stacktrace as well.
I read online and it says that this is an issue with python 2.x, but I am getting in python 3.4

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec(sentences, workers=num_workers, \
        size=num_features, min_count = min_word_count, \
        window = context, sample = downsampling)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 3, in <module>
    window = context, sample = downsampling)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.build_vocab(sentences)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 483, in build_vocab
    self.finalize_vocab()  # build tables & arrays
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 611, in finalize_vocab
    self.reset_weights()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 888, in reset_weights
    self.syn0[i] = self.seeded_vector(self.index2word[i] + str(self.seed))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 900, in seeded_vector
    once = random.RandomState(uint32(self.hashfxn(seed_string)))
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that python (2 and 3) support integers of [arbitrary size](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) - python will just keep on adding additional "digits" (actually groups of them in `long`s) when you reach the current maximum size. The only differences between py2 and py3 is that the former will start with an actual C `int` or `long` before going to the arbitrary size python `long`. In py3, you always get the python `long` type.

Long story short: check the size of your integers.